# Zend Form captcha Decorator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

Zend Captcha generates 3 elements together are captcha image, hidden input element, input text box for captcha code respectively and places them side by side without any separator.
I want to decorate captcha image tag only in captcha element being generated by zend form captcha. And leave input elements intact.
**I don't want to create custom decorator class for it.**

Is there any way to do this?

I delve into zend decorator where I see $_separator variable. Can it be helpful?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.zend_form > img {
    border: 10px solid red;
}
</style>
```

if you want only visual decoration :)

what do u want to do with captcha element? insert pre|post text? describe